# AJAX Friend Activity With AJAX, MySQL And PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm building a system to show a bit of real time activity on a web system I've been developing, the problem is I'm not very sure how I can do this and make it real time with AJAX.

Basically, I have a rates table, full of music ratings, and whenever someone likes or '+1's' a song, I'd like to make it show on this real time activity thing.

I would start off with some code, but I'm not too sure how to do any AJAX at all!

Does anyone have any idea how I could stream real time data through a box, one 'story' at a time?

Comment: Pick something like jQuery(), for ex. [ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Comment: there are a few ways to do it: ajax with long polling, html5 websockets, XMPP, flash sockets. http://www.ape-project.org/ , http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/long-polling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add jQuery to your page and you can easily do that with `$.ajax()`.  Say you have a PHP script cleverly named ajax.php which accepted a `GET` param named `song_id` or something.

Now let's say that you have a +1 link whose html `id` attribute was suffixed with the song's id (referencing the song id in the rates table).

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="like-34" class="like-link">Like</a>
<span id="current-likes-34">5</span>
```

Let's see the ajax call quick (which gets triggered when the user clicks the like link):

```
$('.like-link').click(function() {
    var songId = this.id.split('-')[1];
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/ajax.php',
        data: 'song_id=' + songId,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            // update likes
            $('#current-likes-' + songId).html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Now, let's take a look at what this arbitrary ajax.php script might look like (simplified):

```
<?php
    // detect AJAX request
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
        && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'
    ) {
        $songId = (isset($_GET['song_id'] && preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $_GET['song_id']) 
            ? (int) $_GET['song_id']
            : 0;

        // assume a mysql db connection has been established
        $sql = sprintf(
            'UPDATE rates SET likes = likes + 1 WHERE song_id = %d',
            $songId
        );
        mysql_query($sql); // run update query

        // now get current amount of likes and print them out to be used by AJAX response
        $result = mysql_query(sprintf('SELECT likes FROM rates WHERE song_id = %s', $songId));
        if ($result) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            echo $row[0]; // print likes
        }
    }
```

---

**Keep in mind** that this is all *hypothetical*.  The PHP script is not complete at all.  My example assumed a lot of things but it should be a sufficient base with which to get started.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible to have this scaling with only a LAMP(PHP) stack. There are a some web services available which help you achieve this(scaling). Just to name a few in random order:

- http://pusher.com/
- http://x-stream.ly/index.html
- http://beaconpush.com/

All have some sort of free plan. I honestly think pusher is a little bit expensive although pretty popular.

I think Beaconpush is the cheapest of these three, but I don't believe it supports SSL, which is pretty necessary when you want to have secure(secret) information cross the wire. You could for example just send ping over the wire via Beaconpush, but retrieve information from your own server securely using SSL.

Finally also X-streamly has pretty generous free plan with support of SSL also. If you need secure connections then I think x-streamly is the best plan for you, with a pretty good price plan of $19 when you get really big, but in the beginning I assume that free plan will get you started.

You  can also use self-hosting solutions like for example http://socket.io or [atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) just to name a few